# How to convert a delimited string into xml structure defined in a variable with XSLT

Tags: xml, arrays, parsing, xslt

I need to parse a tab-delimited string into an xml node structure defined in a variable. I used tokenize() to get the string into an "array" variable and have a variable that tells me what tag I should give to each element in the array based on its position. I do a for-each on the array and assign each element in it to an xml tag to produce the output.

Here's the input:

```
<Data>Jane Doe /t Atlantis /t 4-1-1999 /t jane@doe.com<Data>
```

Here's the XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyXMLStructure">
    <Field Position="1">Name</Field>
    <Field Position="2">Location</Field>
    <Field Position="3">DateOfBirth</Field>
    <Field Position="4">Email</Field>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="processData">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>

    <xsl:variable name="DataFields" select="tokenize($pText, '&#x9;')"/>
    <xsl:element name="PersonData">

        <xsl:for-each select="$DataFields">
            <xsl:element name="{$MyXMLStructure/Field[@Position = position()]}">
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="processData">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="/Data"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's the expected output:

```
<PersonData>
     <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
     <Location>Atlantis</Location>
     <DateOfBirth>4-1-1999</DateOfBirth>
     <Email>jane@doe.com</Email>
</PersonData>
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid Element Name. Invalid QName {Name Location ...}
```

I'm guessing that the position() of the array isn't working well and the name of the element isn't being assigned properly.

Please help!

EDIT: Edited XSLT code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$DataFields">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$MyXMLStructure/Field[@Position = $pos]}">
             <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

For a more efficient access you could define a key `<xsl:key name="k1" match="Field" use="xs:integer(@Position)"/>` and then use `<xsl:element name="{key('k1', position(), $MyXMLStructure)}">`.

Comment: That worked! Can't believe it could've been so simple. Thank you!

Comment: @helderdarocha Yes I had to wait 4 minutes to mark it as correct.